# Given HTML string, generate the TailwindCSS programatically

Tags: node.js, tailwind-css

Given an HTML string (generated from server) using the TailwindCSS classes, how to generate the TailwindCSS from that HTML.

Answer (score 1):

We can use PostCSS with TailwindCSS plugin to generate the CSS.
To provide the HTML for TailwindCSS, use `{raw: html}` in the content.

```js
import postcss from "postcss";
import tailwindcss from "tailwindcss"
import autoprefixer from "autoprefixer"
import cssnano from "cssnano"

async function generateTailwindCss(html) {
  return (await postcss([tailwindcss({
    content: [{ raw:html }],
    theme: {
      extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
  }), autoprefixer, cssnano])
  .process(`
    @tailwind base;
    @tailwind components;
    @tailwind utilities;
  `)).css
}

const css = generateTailwindCss('<div class="m-4">HTML content</div>')
```